# Changing image on scroll using jQuery in PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a php website, I have a background image of a road, and 2 images of a character, when the user scrolls, I want the images to change till the section is over, such that it looks like the character is moving.

I did the following code in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop())
<?php for($i=30;$i<=2500;$i++){ ?>
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= <?=$i?>){
      // set to new image
      $(".bgimg img").attr("src","char1.png");
    } else {
      //back to default
      $(".bgimg img").attr("src","char2.png");
    }
    <?php } ?>
  })
})
```

```css
.bgimg {
      background-image: url('road.png');
      height: 2500px;
      background-size:cover;
      width:50%


  }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
<div class="row">
  <p>This is a test </p>
</div>

<div class="row bgimg" >

<img src="char1.png" id="chara">
</div>
</div>
```

however it doesn't work. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That whole PHP loop in there looks to be pretty nonsensical. You are doing the exact same thing in each of those thousands of if and else branches you are creating there - so what is the point in having those thousands of conditions, only to check if a value is >= 30 first, then >= 31 next, etc. ...?

Comment: Clearly this PHP code won't run in a code snippet here.  What's the actual JavaScript code that this produces?  (You might find that it's a bit... unwieldy.)  In what way is *that* code not doing what you expect?  Basically, first understand and define what you want your JavaScript code to do.  Then, if there's a need for it (and there probably isn't), use PHP to output that JavaScript code.

Comment: @CBroe i understand, the loop is also making the page load slow, is there any alternate way to change the images till the section ends?

Comment: Check if you are in between the top and the bottom of the section then, with your current scroll position. That doesn't need _any_ loops.

Comment: (FYI, if you wanted to do this using current / more performant methods, then this would be a use case for the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this can answer because I'm not sure I understood what you want but here are examples that may be able to help you (without PHP loop)

```
<script>
$(function(){   
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {

        if($(this).scrollTop()>30)  $(".bgimg img").attr("src","char2.png");
        else $(".bgimg img").attr("src","char1.png");

    });
}); 
</script>
```

With the **script above** the image changes with the threshold of 30

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
With the **script below** the image changes alternately as the user "scrolls" the page.

With the following HTML code

```
<div id="characterDiv"><img id="characterImage" src="char1.png"></div>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
With a long text page to have a high enough window
</p>
```

With this CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">
    html { font-family:Arial; font-size: 0.9em; }
    p { width: 50%; text-align: justify; }

    #characterDiv {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
    }

    </style>
```

And this JQuery Script (without PHP Loop but with Mathematics)

```
    <script>
    $(function(){   
        $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    
            let pitch = 150;
    
            // Display for Test
            console.log($(this).scrollTop()+' -> '+(Math.round($(this).scrollTop()/pitch))%2);
    
            // This calculation gives alternately 0 or 1
            if((Math.round($(this).scrollTop()/pitch))%2==0)    $("#characterImage").attr("src","char2.png");
            else $("#characterImage").attr("src","char1.png");
    
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: i want to switch between images, that is when the user scrolls on, the image should keep on changin from 1 and 2

Comment: With this script if you scroll down or up, images change

Comment: @ZubairNazar I modified my answer (in the second script, if that's what you want, you can adjust the pitch)